# Multiple @OA\Response() with the same response="200"

Tags: laravel, swagger, openapi

I'm using DarkaOnLine L5-Swagger package for the api documentation for laravel app. I'm facing this issue when generating api docs.On my local this is working fine but I get an exception on server. I have double checked if I'm duplicating the response in my controller but it's not case.

[image]

Comment: Muhammad are you using windows or ubuntu for development and production?

Comment: @Raju it's windows. and product server is aws

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I have windows for development and aws for production. I don't know why it is the problem.

Try response='default' instead of '200' if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What i did was generated api docs in a json form of output and placed it on my live site directory of swagger api docs.

Answer (score 0):

you must type rout with capitals latter
like if it is post then first letter of post has to be capital "Post"

Answer (score 0):

in your browser address bar check if you have **https://** then remove **s** and remain **http://** check if the error is fixed, it's working on my side

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).